# How to enforce conventional commit messages in git (Bitbucket)

Tags: bash, git, bitbucket, git-commit

I'm looking for a way to prevent commits which have no correct format for the commit message. 
I intend to use the following convention:
https://www.conventionalcommits.org/en/v1.0.0/

I found out there is a folder with bash scripts which may be the key to that solution: `.git/hooks/`

However, I'm not sure how to write the script to enforce the format on the commit messages.

Will edit accordingly, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

There is a list of [Tools](https://www.conventionalcommits.org/en/about/) in the documentation.

My suggestion would be to:

1. Pick a tool.
2. Run it from the command line, and see if you can get it to check commit messages.
3. Put the commands you use to check commits messages in a git hook.

Answer (score 0):

The official Conventional Commits website maintains [a list of tools](https://www.conventionalcommits.org/en/about/#tooling-for-conventional-commits) to aid in enforcement, management and configuration.

<sup>I've linked to it directly, as it isn't immediately obvious on the site where that is. For anyone curious, it is under the "about" section.</sup>

The list is not exhaustive, but a very good place to start. The tools are varied, ranging from "complete" solutions that handle rule enforcement and standards, to "helpers" that simplify a single part of the process. Explore and find the tools that work best for you.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34785536)